# How to Create a video in Android?

Tags: android, video-processing, video-encoding

I am new to android. I have two files of same length, One is audio file and one is video file with no audio. I want to make a video with audio by combining these two files.  Help me to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I assume you have native Android app and familiarity with Java (or know porting the code in native C) and are willing to use other open-source classes in your project.*

This is what you might give a head-start: Since this project is not actively maintained now, you might have to fork and use their logic into your code.

https://github.com/tqnst/MP4ParserMergeAudioVideo

Another alternative is using [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) port for Android (however I am not sure how this works natively).

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java